# Why won't Thunderbird report notifications to the indicator-applet on 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, indicator, thunderbird, messaging-menu

Just upgraded to 12.04 from 11.04, using the default Unity desktop. I don't seem to be getting anything from the Messaging indicator applet. I'm running all the default things that I installed this morning: Thunderbird 11.01 with Global Menu Bar Integration 3.2 and Messaging Menu and Unity Integration 0.9.3. I go Preferences -> When new message arrives -> Show an alert, Play Sound. But nothing happens. No sound, no notification, no change in color of the Messaging indicator, but Thunderbird clearly shows new messages. I tried installing notification-daemon but that didn't do anything either, even after another restart. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thunderbird reports new emails out of the box on my Ubuntu 12.04 install. No need for a plugin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have recently gotten these notifications to work. I'm not sure if this will work for everyone. I'm also not sure if this is a bug or not. It seems more like an oversight of forgotten software that should be installed by default. I installed the following packages to get everything (sound, bubble, messaging indicator) to work:

```
sudo apt-get install notification-daemon esound python-notify
```

Good luck to everyone else having problems with this!