# Thunderbird's Indicator Doesn't Show the Bubbles in 13.04

Tags: unity, 13.04, indicator, thunderbird

I have tried the solutions that I found here.  These two, mainly: [Why won't Thunderbird report notifications to the indicator-applet on 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125778/why-wont-thunderbird-report-notifications-to-the-indicator-applet-on-12-04) and [Why aren't certain indicators showing in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/271157/why-arent-certain-indicators-showing-in-unity) (I have made that array that to 'all') But I still don't get a bubble when I get an new e-mail.  Suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with some extensions. I'm using **[Mail Box Alert](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/mailbox-alert/?src=search)** and it does what I need...

Comment: Eh, it's nice but it doesn't really fit with Unity and Ubuntu.  I like the idea but still, I like the old way with Unity's bubbles.