# Thunderbird tray icon show new emails?

Tags: indicator, thunderbird

I use Ubuntu 16.04 with Thunderbird 45.4. When I receive a new email, I want the Thunderbird tray icon in the right upper corner to change (so that I know that I have an unread email). I saw somewhere that the icon should turn into the blue color. But my icon remains the same all the time. How can I change that?

tltr:
Why does the Thunderbird tray icon not turn blue when a new email arrives?

EDIT:
 Is it possible that the method described at this old link [Why won't Thunderbird report notifications to the indicator-applet on 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125778/why-wont-thunderbird-report-notifications-to-the-indicator-applet-on-12-04/126623#126623) would help?

The only reason I don't want to try what is described in the link above immediately is that I don't know how to undo the changes performed by "sudo apt-get install notification-daemon esound python-notify" (I am new to Ubuntu). If someone tells me how undo the changes then I will try and see.

SOLVED:
It turned out that my Thunderbird tray icon did never turn blue because a Firefox extension Gmail Notifier accesses the new emails first. When I turnd this extension off, everything started to work well.

Comment: I'm not aware of any setting - for me it just works. If you just set up your email account, maybe you need to relogin/reboot...

Comment: Is it possible that the method described at this old link http://askubuntu.com/questions/125778/why-wont-thunderbird-report-notifications-to-the-indicator-applet-on-12-04/126623#126623 would help?

Comment: The only reason I don't want to try what is described in the link above immediately is that I don't know how to undo the changes performed by sudo apt-get install notification-daemon esound python-notify (I am new to Ubuntu). If someone tells me how undo the changes then I will try and see.

Comment: If it works, it would give you something else but what you asked for - that the messages menu turns blue. Also, it's old stuff, and may not fit well on 16.04. (Trying isn't dangerous - if you install those packages, and you don't like the result, you can simply remove them again. If you do, it's `esound-common`, not `esound`.)